# One or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have been trying for a bit to see where the flaw in a method that I created that Updates (including Add) an object and it's children using Entity Framework 6.0. I have looked at all the other SO questions and am not able to see where I am going wrong. I have a Product Entity which can have a list of children, and those children can have a list of children.

Here is my Product Entity

```
public partial class Product
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Product()
    {
        ProductSizes = new HashSet<ProductSize>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? PortfolioId { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public int UpdatedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }

    // This is a lookup entity that contains 1:1 relationship
    public virtual Portfolio Portfolio { get; set; }

    // This is a lookup entity that contains 1:1 relationship
    public virtual User CreatedByUser { get; set; }

    // This is a lookup entity that contains 1:1 relationship
    public virtual User UpdatedByUser{ get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<ProductSize> ProductSizes { get; set; }
}
```

Product can have many children ProductSize

```
public partial class ProductSize
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public ProductSize()
    {
        ProductPackages = new HashSet<ProductPackage>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Product")]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public int? CanSizeId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string CanUPC { get; set; }

    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public int UpdatedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    // This is a lookup entity that contains 1:1 relationship
    public virtual CanSize CanSize { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<ProductPackage> ProductPackages { get; set; }

    // Parent Product
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; } 

    // This is a lookup entity that contains 1:1 relationship
    public virtual User CreatedByUser{ get; set; }

    // This is a lookup entity that contains 1:1 relationship
    public virtual User UpdatedByUser{ get; set; }
}
```

And ProductSize can have many ProductPackage

```
public partial class ProductPackage
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public ProductPackage()
    {          
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductSize")]
    public int ProductSizeId { get; set; }

    public int PackageSizeId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string CarrierCode { get; set; }

    public int? SAPId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string CaseUPCSupplierPack { get; set; }

    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public int UpdatedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    // This is a lookup entity that contains 1:1 relationship
    public virtual PackageSize PackageSize { get; set; }

    // This is a lookup entity that contains 1:1 relationship
    public virtual User CreatedByUser{ get; set; }

    // Parent ProductSize
    public virtual ProductSize ProductSize { get; set; }

    // This is a lookup entity that contains 1:1 relationship
    public virtual User UpdatedByUser{ get; set; }
}
```

I than have a method that accepts a Product and updates it, as well adds any entities down the chain if needed.

```
public void UpdateProduct(Product product, int userId)
{
    var originalProduct = GetAllProductEntities().Where(a => a.Id == product.Id).SingleOrDefault();

    var prouctEntry = _dbContext.Entry(originalProduct);
    prouctEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(newProduct);

    foreach (var size in newProduct.ProductSizes)
    {
        var originalSize = originalProduct.ProductSizes.Where(a => a.Id == size.Id).SingleOrDefault();

        if (originalSize != null)
        {

            var sizeEntry = _dbContext.Entry(originalSize);
            sizeEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(size);
        }
        else
        {
            // No -> It's a new child item -> Insert
            size.Id = 0;
            originalProduct.ProductSizes.Add(size);
        }
        foreach (var package in size.ProductPackages)
        {
            var originalPackage = originalSize.ProductPackages.Where(a => a.Id == package.Id).SingleOrDefault();

            if (originalPackage != null)
            {

                var packageEntry = _dbContext.Entry(originalPackage);
                packageEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(package);
            }
            else
            {
                // No -> It's a new child item -> Insert
                package.Id = 0;
                originalSize.ProductPackages.Add(package);
            }
        }
    }
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

After SaveChanges() is called, I get this System.InvalidOperationException

> 'The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.'

As said, I have read most of the SO question/answers regarding this and I believe it is an issue with my model, but I am lost as to what it could be. This model was generated from an Existing DB so if there is an issue with my schema I can change that as well. I can provide further code snippets as well if needed.

Comment: This line of code looks suspicious:  `var originalPackage = originalSize.ProductPackages.Where(a => a.Id == size.Id).SingleOrDefault();`  Should that be: `a.Id == package.Id).SingleOrDefault()` instead?

Comment: whoops that is a copy paste error, I fixed the original post, but it does not work with that there

Comment: Can you call ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()? that might be a issue, as the internal image is differing from your new values. Otherwise, I'd suspect there is somewhere a ProductPackage without a containing ProductSize object.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro where should I be calling DetectChanges()? right before SaveChanges()?

Comment: In addition to @DevilSuichiro there could be sizes or packages that are not in the ProductSizes or in the SizePackages collection so EF wants to unrelate (not delete) them from products or sizes (you probably set the cascade delete to SetNull). To debug it you could change the foreign keys to int? to check wich objects are updated. Just for debug you can disable model check, set the fks to int? and trace the queries (SQL Server will throw an exception because the column is defined as non nullable but you should be able to see the query that EF try to run).

Comment: @bubi I have tried what you are asking, but no matter what I do I get the same error. I have even updated the db to make the FK nullable but I get the same thing. Is there anything I can show that may be glaring?